# attempted relative import in non-package error in mavlink

Tags: python-2.7, package

I've already looked through the forums, but I haven't found an answer that is mavlink specific.

I am currently writing script in python, and I want to use a python module of mavlink.
The documentation for mavlink tells me to run mavgenerate.py from my mavlink folder. When I run this script, a gui appears asking for my xml files, a specified output directory, and what language I want my headers in. mavgenerate.py works when I choose to make headers for C, but it gives me the error: "attempted relative import in non-package" when I try to choose python. 
my xml files is located at:

C:\Python27\mavlink\message_definitions\v1.0

and I have my python module output directory as:

C:\Python27\mavlink\pymavlink\include

below is a screenshot of my error.

[image: screenshot]

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you move your working directories out of c:\Python27 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old  question but i have just encountered with this problem. Solution that i have applied is: in mavgenerate.py replace following lines

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join('pymavlink','generator'))
from mavgen import *
```

with

```
from pymavlink.generator.mavgen import *
```

I dont know the exact reason of the problem but from 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) thread i assume problem lies with python's interpretation of directories as packages.

I have used python 2.7. Tried though to do with python 3.4 but didn't had chance there.